# What is the scope used in VSCode snippets for vue files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm creating a snippet file for my project. However, I only want to defined the scope for some snippets for **Vue Files** only. Of course I know I can omit the scope property to apply it in all kinds of files, but I don't want that.

I tried different options (`vue, html, vuejs`) like this:

[image]

However this snippet is not being displayed.

[image]

If I removed the scope, the snippet is displayed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I don't want this, because it shows up in all kinds of files where I don't need it.

I searched in the official documentation in: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-scope
but they don't show the list of different possibilities, including of course VueJS.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used **vue-html** scope. Now is working only for Vue files.

```
"My snippet for vue": {
        "scope": "vue-html",
        "prefix": "hv",
        "body": [
            "Hello vue",
        ],
    },
```

[image]

**IMPORTANT:** It only shows inside `<template>` tag.

- If you need them inside `<script>` tag, you need to add `javascript`
  in the scope. *It is going to be displayed in all `javascript`
  files*.
- If you need them inside `<style>` tag, you need to add `css` in the
  scope. *It is going to be displayed in all `css` files*.

Final code:

```
"My snippet for vue": {
        "scope": "vue-html,javascript,css",
        "prefix": "hv",
        "body": [
            "Hello vue",
        ],
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you command palette and type `Create Snippet`, you'll have the choice for all of those regarding Vue.

[image]

Like you, I usually take `vue-html`.

Comment: Sorry for my little knowledge, but how do you "command palette"? How can I see that list?

Comment: Oh! I saw this. You can invoke the command palette by typing Ctrl + Shift + P. But I typed  `Create Snippet` and it shows `No matching commands`

Comment: You then probably have some error in your VScode config or alike. That one is a default thing as far as I know. Maybe check your settings (`Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`) to see if you don't have any kind of warning (bottom left of your VScode interface, with the warning icon).

Comment: Oh, also launch the snippet command from a Vue file. It may not work if you're already into a config file of some sort. @JotaPardo

Comment: I tried from different kind of files, config, vue, and others, that command is not being displayed for me. Maybe because I already have a .code-snippets file created

Comment: Try it like that: https://share.cleanshot.com/Zdq1c8 Have the same issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248988/discussion-between-jotapardo-and-kissu).